# Player Context in iOS Spotify SDK

Tags: ios, spotify

In the Android SDK docs https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/app-remote-lib/docs/

there is a PlayerContext class, which represents the current context of the player - such as an album or a playlist - and its metadata.

However, I can't find its equivalent in the iOS SDK. Is there an analogous class?

Comment: Have you looked at `SPTAppRemotePlayerState`? From Spotify - "The SPTAppRemotePlayerState represents the state within the Spotify player."

Comment: SPTAppRemotePlayerState contains id<SPTAppRemoteTrack> track, playbackPosition, playbackSpeed, paused, id<SPTAppRemotePlaybackRestrictions> playbackRestrictions, and id<SPTAppRemotePlaybackOptions> playbackOptions.

There is no context member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in version 1.01 of the [iOS SDK](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk).

The documentation for the feature is [here](https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/html/Protocols/SPTAppRemotePlayerState.html).